# how to get the current scope in python

Tags: python, scope

is there any reference to point to the current scope , i look up many articles and couldn't find the answer ,for example i want to print every var's content in current scope

```
for x in list(locals()):
    print(x)
```

but only give me this,the var's name

```
__builtins__
__file__
__package__
__cached__
__name__
__doc__
```

i dont want code like this

```
print(__builtins__)
print(__file__)
print(__package__)
print(__cached__)
print(__name__)
print(__doc__)
....
```

Comment: The underscore variables ARE part of your current scope. If you don't want them, just skip them.

Comment: @gecco he wants to print the values of the variables, not to skip them. The for loop in his post prints the name of the variables, not there vaues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Massive overkill... Wrap the filtering and printing of local namespace in a function.

I don't recommend this. I'm posting it predominantly to show it can be done and to get comments.

```
import inspect

def print_local_namespace():
    ns = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals
    for k, v in ns.iteritems():
        if not k.startswith('__'):
            print '{0} : {1}'.format(k, v)


def test(a, b):
    c = 'Freely'
    print_local_namespace()
    return a + b + c


test('I', 'P')
```

Comment: This is iterating over call stack frames, not definition scopes. You want to got to parent scopes, not parent stack frames.

Answer (score 6):

To also get the values, you can use:

```
for symbol, value in locals().items():
    print symbol, value
```

locals() gives you a dict. Iterating over a dict gives you its keys. To get the list of (key, value) pairs, use the items method.

Comment: if u run your code,will show you these,RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: what version of python are you using? Ihave changed the code to something working with 2.7

Comment: This fails in Python 3.6 with the same RuntimeError.

Comment: to avoid the RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration, use this code: d = { k : v for k,v in locals().items() if v} to copy the dictionary and then print the symbol and value like above.

Answer (score 2):

To print only those variable names in `locals()` which do not start with `'__'`:

```
for local_var in list(locals()):
    if not local_var.startswith('__'): print local_var
```

Comment: Great hack for getting Python2 "f-strings", `"i wish I had f-strings".format(**locals())`

Comment: This worked for me in Python 3 with the tweak `print(local_var)`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "current scope"? If you mean only the local variables, then `locals()` is the correct answer.
If you mean all the identifiers that you can use[locals + globals + *nonlocals*] than things get messier. Probably the simpler solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430811/enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here) one.

If you don't want the `__.*__` variables, just filter them out.